# Dimensions of Ker and Im for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble with this problem. I know I should be using the theorem that $ \dim(\operatorname{im} T) = \dim(V) - \dim(\operatorname{Ker} T)$ to solve this question but I''m stuck on where to start.

For a linear map $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,$ what are the possible values of ($\dim \operatorname{Ker}T, \dim \operatorname{im} T$)?

The answer should be a pair of numbers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\ker{\operatorname{Ker}}\def\im{\operatorname{Im}}$
Since $\ker T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, its dimension is $\leq3$; similarly $\dim\im T\leq2$. Further we have the constraint $\dim\ker T+\dim\im T=\dim\mathbb R^3=3$. So there are three possible pairs $(\dim\ker T,\dim\im T)=(3,0),(2,1),(1,2)$.

---

Here are examples of linear maps in each of the three cases:

$T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ defined as

$
\begin{matrix}
1.&T(x,y,z)=(0,0),&\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb R.\\
2.&T(x,y,z)=(x,0),&\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb R.\\
3.&T(x,y,z)=(x,y),&\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb R.\\
\end{matrix}
$

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could there be 4 possible pairs since (3,0) can be written as (0.3) or can you not swap them like such?

Comment: Note the constraint $\dim\operatorname{Im} T\leq2$, since $\operatorname{Im}T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.